# My western digital harddisk does not get detected on my macbook pro and imac

Tags: mac, hard-drive, macbook, external-hard-drive

I accidently pulled out my western digital harddisk and ever since its not getting detected on my macbook pro and imac. The error msg which pops up says "`The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer`".

I want to get my HDD working again and i don't mind losing the data.
Can you please suggest some solution to format and get the hard disk working again.

Disk utility detects the drive but none of the repair options are enabled.

Comment: you'd try to startup from your OSX installer CD/DVD and repair from there...

Comment: Can you elaborate a lil more on the steps?

Comment: Also add it as an answer so that i can upvote it.

Comment: what's your HD format ? NTFS or FAT32 or else ?

Answer (score 1):

you'd try to startup from your OSX installer CD/DVD and repair from there

Comment: I am not sure of the HD format, its mac os compatible. I accidently pulled the usb plug out and ever since i am getting this error.

Comment: Erase it using Mac Disk Utility.  Then try the partitioning again
If it fails again, use Disk First Aid on it to see if it has errors.

Comment: When i use mac disk utility the options are not enabled. However in the left panel i can see the HD.

Comment: so you'd try to boot up with the CD/DVD surely =)